# Gulp. Зачем нужен callback в задаче?

Tags: gulp, npm, сборка

Иногда в gulpfile встречаю такую конструкцию:

```
gulp.task("build", function(cb) {
  run(
    "clean",
    "copy",
    "style",
    "images",
    "js",
    cb
  );
});
```

Зачем тут нужен коллбек (т.е. cb)? В каких ситуациях он применяется?

Comment: Уважаемые пользователи. Если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, просьба не забывать помечать его как ответ! Это важно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В официальной документации написано, что **cb** завершает таск, в асинхронных запросах.

```
cb(err); // return error
cb(); // finished task
```